Do FCM Topic Registrations Expire in a Flutter App?
I have a Flutter app that sends notifications to an FCM topic. The app is notification-based and does not require users to open it after the initial setup. I’m concerned about how FCM works with topic registrations. Specifically, I want to know if topic registrations expire like device tokens do. No targeted notifications using tokens are needed, only topic-based notifications.
Clarification Needed:

Do FCM topic subscriptions expire like device tokens?
Is there anything specific I need to handle to ensure my app remains subscribed to the topics over time?


As per documentation

Topics are a mechanism which allow a device to subscribe and unsubscribe from named PubSub channels, all managed via FCM

Topics won't expire as per documentation.
For handling subscription to topics, please make sure to run await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("topic"); when user logged in, and await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic('weather'); when user is logged out or when you don't want to make your app listen to a topic.
However, when a topic is subscribed, the application keeps listening to topic even when it is on background or killed, unless the topic is unsubscribed.
